# Laravel - Is there a way to generate /photo/new and /photo/id without using resource controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

These are the urls that I want to generate:

(1) /photo/new - for creating new photo

(2) /photo/id - for viewing specific photo

Without using resource controller, for (1) I can implement getNew() and postNew() method.

As for (2) I thought I could implement getIndex($id) but the url would then become /photo/index/id

I know for a fact that you can generate (2) by using resource controller with the default show() method.
I would like to know if there's a way to do it without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
Route::get('/photos/new', array('as'=>'photos.new','uses'=>'PhotosController@new'));
Route::get('/photos/{id}', array('as'=>'photos.show','uses'=>'PhotosController@show'));
```

And you controller

```
class PhotosController extends Controller {

    public function new()
    {
              ...
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
              ...
    }

}
```